How to add every 8th column to a graph in Excel VBA
I am stuck on how to add only every 8th column of data starting from column Z. The range should always be from row 27 to 194.
This is the code I currently have for creating the graph. I want to replace the manual range (Z$27:Z$194,AH$27:AH$194,...) with something other because I have a lot of columns.
Thanks in advance for any help!
Sub Graph_VBA()
Cells(713, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLineMarkersStacked100).Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Z$27:Z$194,AH$27:AH$194,AP$27:AP$194,AX$27:AX$194,BF$27:BN$194,BF$27:BN$194")
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Winter"
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Height = 400
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Width = 750
ActiveChart.Parent.Cut
Cells(713, 1).PasteSpecial
End Sub



First, let's try not to use Select:
Sub Graph_VBA()
    Dim shp AS Shape, cht AS Chart
    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLineMarkersStacked100)
    Set cht = shp.Chart
    cht.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Z$27:Z$194,AH$27:AH$194,AP$27:AP$194,AX$27:AX$194,BF$27:BN$194,BF$27:BN$194")
    cht.ChartTitle.Text = "Winter"
    cht.ChartArea.Height = 400
    cht.ChartArea.Width = 750
    shp.Top = ActiveSheet.Cells(713, 1).Top
    shp.Left = ActiveSheet.Cells(713, 1).Left
End Sub

Next, let's use the SeriesCollection object (and, more specifically, the SeriesCollection.Add method) to add our columns one-by-one with a loop, instead of all at once:
Sub Graph_VBA()
    Dim shp AS Shape, cht AS Chart, i as Long, col AS Long, rng AS Range
    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLineMarkersStacked100)
    Set cht = shp.Chart
    
    For i = 1 to 6 'Add 6 columns
        col = 26 + ((i-1)*8) 'Every 8th column, starting at Z (26)
        Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(27, col), _
            ActiveSheet.Cells(194, col)) 'Rows 27 to 194
        'Add "Rng", as a Data Column, with a Header in the first row, and Replace existing data
        cht.SeriesCollection.Add rng, xlColumns, True, True
    Next i
    
    cht.ChartTitle.Text = "Winter"
    cht.ChartArea.Height = 400
    cht.ChartArea.Width = 750
    shp.Top = ActiveSheet.Cells(713, 1).Top
    shp.Left = ActiveSheet.Cells(713, 1).Left
End Sub


Thank you for your suggestion! Unfortunately when I try to execute the code I get the following error: "Invalid next control variable reference" in the line with "Next col".
What could the issue be?

@Wanheda Sorry, I was originally looping the Columns directly (i.e. For col=26 to 66 Step 8), but later changed to using the i variable instead.  It seems that I forgot to change Next col to Next i

Thank you, this fixed the error. On the other hand, unfortunately the resulting plot is not what I wanted. I added the resulting plot in the original post (left side in the screenshot). The result I want should look similar to the plot on the right, which I created manually.

@Wanheda Unfortunately, it's a bit hard to debug without any data.  One thing that might be worth noting is that I assumed Row 27 contains a Header.  If it doesn't — i.e. it contains the first row of data — then you'll want to change cht.SeriesCollection.Add rng, xlColumns, True, True to cht.SeriesCollection.Add rng, xlColumns, False, False

One more question, I also want to repeat the same graph for spring, summer and fall. I replaced the variable "i" with "o","p" and "u" and changed the location of the graph to rows further down but it prints every data set into the same last graph instead of 4 different ones.

cht.ChartTitle.Text = "Spring"
cht.ChartArea.Height = 400
cht.ChartArea.Width = 750
shp.Top = ActiveSheet.Cells(730, 1).Top
shp.Left = ActiveSheet.Cells(730, 1).Left
For p = 1 To 50 'Add 50 columns
    col = 26 + ((p - 1) * 8)
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(199, col), _
        ActiveSheet.Cells(366, col)) 'Rows 199 to 366
    'Add "Rng", as a Data Column, with a Header in the first row, and Replace existing data
    cht.SeriesCollection.Add rng, xlColumns, False, False
Next p


@Wanheda The Set shp = [..] line creates a new ChartObject on the Worksheet, and then the Set cht = shp.Chart line tells it to start putting data into the newly created chart.  So, you will need to make sure that you copy those two lines too — but i is only used in the loop, so you don't need to change that to o, p, and u
